# Fiware Keystone API Create User

Tags: openstack, fiware, keystone

We are trying to create users in Fiware IDM using Keystone Identity API.

We are sending the following curl command

```
curl -s \
 -H "X-Auth-Token: e746971040657101bb1e" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"user": {"name": "newuser", "password": "changeme"}}' \
 http://localhost:35357/v3/users | python -mjson.tool
```

The token we have used is the one configured in keystone.conf

```
admin_token=e746971040657101bb1e
```

But the result we are getting is the following

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401, 
        "message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", 
        "title": "Unauthorized"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about what can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas for you.

One is that the port value 35357 is not for the admin API calls, it's intended for user calls.

Also since you are using the v3 API I believe that the token can't be used when creating a user unless you are indicating a domain.

However I can't tell from your curl command what action you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, adding domain_id it worked. Now I have another issue with createProject. I am doing curl -s POST -H “X-Auth-token: e746971040657101bb1e” -H “Content-type:application/json” \
-d '{ \
“project”: {
“description”: “development”,
“domain_id”: “default”,
“enabled”: true,
“name”: “development”
}
}' \
http://localhost:5000/v3/projects | python -mjson.tool, but I'm getting "error": {
        "code": 401, 
        "message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", 
        "title": "Unauthorized"
    }, do you know why?

Comment: Solved removing POST in curl