# Fiware keystone api create user and access with horizon

Tags: json, api, fiware, keystone

im using keystone api to create an user (as in [Fiware Keystone API Create User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411266/fiware-keystone-api-create-user/31411884#31411884)).

my steps:

create project with:

> curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -d '{"tenant": {"description":"Project1",
>   "name":"proyecto1", "enabled": true}}'
>   http://localhost:35357/v2.0/tenants -X POST | python
>   -mjson.tool

create role:

> curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -d '{"role":{"name":"Project1Admin",
>   "description":"Role Admin for project1"}}'
>   http://localhost:35357/v3/roles  | python -mjson.tool

Create user:

> curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" -d '{"user": {"default_project_id":
>   "d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e", "description":"admin1",
>   "enabled":true, "name":"admin", "password":"admin",
>   "email":"admin@gmail.com"}}' http://localhost:35357/v2.0/users  |
>   python -mjson.tool

last step: create user-role-tenant relationship:

> curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" 
>   http://localhost:35357/v2.0/tenants/d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e/users/admin1/roles/OS-KS/0c10f475076345368724a03ccd1c3403
>   -X PUT

if i check user:

curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" http://localhost:5000/v3/users/admin1 | python -mjson.tool

response:

```
{
    "user": {
        "default_project_id": "d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e",
        "description": "admin1",
        "domain_id": "default",
        "email": "admin1@gmail.com",
        "enabled": true,
        "id": "admin1",
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost:5000/v3/users/admin1"
        },
        "name": "admin1",
        "username": null
    }
}
```

I think thats good, But I try to connect with horizon and have an error "Invalid user or password". The result im getting in logs is the following :

keystone.log

```
2016-04-20 07:56:03.949 2150 WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [-] Could not find user: admin1@gmail.com
2016-04-20 07:56:03.967 2150 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [-] 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2016 07:56:03] "HEAD /v3/OS-TWO-FACTOR/two_factor_auth?user_name=admin1%40gmail.com&domain_name=Default HTTP/1.1" 404 159 0.077033
```

horizon.log:

```
[Wed Apr 20 07:59:41.934935 2016] [:error] [pid 5963:tid
140154061260544] Login failed for user "admin1@gmail.com".
```

Anyone knows why this user cant connect with horizon?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In KeyRock, we use the `name` field to store the user email, and the `username` field to store its username. When creating a user, all attributes provided in the request but the `name`, the `username`, the `default_project_id`, the `domain_id` and the `enabled` attribute are serialized and stored inside a field called `extra`. Therefore, your `email` attribute will be stored in the `extra` field.

After registering, when loging in to Horizon and providing the user email, Horizon sends a request to Keystone to search for the email in the `name` field. Since you are entering `admin1@gmail.com`, but the actual name you provided is `admin1`, login into Horizon will fail.

Registering the user again with `admin1@gmail.com` as name (and not email) should fix your problem, but you can also enter `admin1` in the email field of the login form if you can't afford to recreate the user.

Hope this solves your issue!