# Keystone create user and permissions by api

Tags: rest, fiware, keystone, fiware-keyrock

I have an instance of Keyrock in fiware lab.

in my app, im trying to create user with api as [Fiware keystone api create user and access with horizon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737454/fiware-keystone-api-create-user-and-access-with-horizon).

now i check user:

curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token:17007fe11124bd71eb60" http://localhost:5000/v3/users/admin | python -mjson.tool

response:

```
> {
>     "user": {
>         "default_project_id": "d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e",
>         "description": "admin",
>         "domain_id": "default",
>         "email": "admin@gmail.com",
>         "enabled": true,
>         "id": "admin",
>         "links": {
>             "self": "http://localhost:5000/v3/users/admin1"
>         },
>         "name": "admin@gmail.com",
>         "username": "admin"
>     } }
```

now name field is correct, but i cant log with this user in my Horizon. If i check the keystone.log, i can see this:

```
2016-09-21 12:28:50.353 1483 WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [-] Authorization failed. The request you have made requires authentication. from 127.0.0.1
2016-09-21 12:28:50.445 1482 WARNING keystone.auth.controllers [-] User admin doesn't have access to default project d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e. The token will be unscoped rather than scoped to the project.
2016-09-21 12:28:50.767 1481 WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [-] You are not authorized to perform the requested action: identity:revoke_token
2016-09-21 12:29:42.900 1483 WARNING keystone.common.controller [-] RBAC: Bypassing authorization
```

and in Horizon:

[image]

Of course, the log explains problem: "*User admin doesn't have access to default project d0f384973b9f4a57b975fcd9bef10c6e*" But, how can i set permissions to this user in project?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the request:

PUT /v3/projects/{project_id}/users/{user_id}/roles/{role_id}

as explained in [Keystone roles documentation](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/index.html?expanded=assign-role-to-user-on-project-detail#roles)

Comment: Ok. I think its the way, but not all. After assign role to project, in horizon  has the same error "session expired" and in keystone.log: "Authorization failed. The request you have made requires authentication". Looking for v3/projects/{idproject}/users/{my_user}/roles returns json with role member...

Comment: @AlvaroAlonso I am having the same issue. The user logs out immediately after loggin in. Hoirzon console shows:

     Login successful for user "umair".
     [10/Jan/2017 13:35:14] "POST /auth/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
     DEBUG:idm_logger:Session expired for user nadeem
     [10/Jan/2017 13:35:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
     Logging out user "umair".
     Could not delete token.

  And the fiware portal shows "Session expired"

Comment: @AngelCid Did you find a solution for this?